# $E^{\bullet} \rightarrow \text{cone}^{\bullet}(u)[-1]$ is a quasi isomorphism

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category with enough injectives. Let $E^\bullet$ be a cochain complex with objects in $\mathcal{A}.$ Let $i^n : E^n \hookrightarrow I^n$. Put $F^n = I^n \oplus I^{n+1}$, $\partial^n = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Let $v^n = \begin{bmatrix} i^n \\ i^{n+1} \partial^n \end{bmatrix}$. Thus we have a monomorphism $v : E^{\bullet} \rightarrow F^{\bullet}$. Let $(u,G^{\bullet})$ be the cokernel. It is claimed that the map
$$\begin{bmatrix} v \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}: E^{\bullet} \rightarrow \text{cone}^{\bullet}(u)[-1]$$
is a quasi isomorphism.

The book has suggested that this is the dual statement of what has been proved in proposition 4.15, Chapter 1 of *Cohomology of sheaves*, Iversen. The proof of the proposition is a bit long to write here. I would be grateful for suggestions as to how i could go about proving this statement following the book's suggestion. Thank you.